# Need a script File to clear Cache Tables in a Drupal Database

Tags: php, mysql, shell, drupal

I need to take a dump of MySQL Database, i usaully do these manual steps do Perform dumping.

    login to phpmyadmin
    select database
    select sql tab
    paste these lines

        TRUNCATE `watchdog`; 
        TRUNCATE `cache`; and
        TRUNCATE `cache_admin_menu`;

And click on OK to clean the cache.

I need to carryout the same activity via sime automated way, so that i can run in Cron job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[root@localhost home]# mysql -u root -ppasswd < /root/Downloads/testscript.sql

I had create one file with name testscript.sql

text in the file as follows

**/*

     * My First MySQL Script - testscript.sql.

     * You need to run this script with an authorized user.

     */

    USE dbname;                     -- Set system database 'dbname' as the current database

    TRUNCATE `cache`;

    TRUNCATE `cache_admin_menu`;

    TRUNCATE `cache_block`;

    TRUNCATE `cache_bootstrap`;

    TRUNCATE `cache_field`;

    TRUNCATE `cache_filter`;

    TRUNCATE `cache_form`;

    TRUNCATE `cache_image`;

    TRUNCATE `cache_libraries`;

    TRUNCATE `cache_menu`;

    TRUNCATE `cache_page`;

    TRUNCATE `cache_path`;

    TRUNCATE `cache_rules`;

    TRUNCATE `cache_token`;

    TRUNCATE `cache_update`;

    TRUNCATE `cache_views`;

    TRUNCATE `watchdog`;**

Comment: TRUNCATE watchdog; worked great for me, have an upvote sir

Answer (score 0):

you can run the following command

```
mysql -u {username} -p{password} -e "FLUSH QUERY CACHE"
```

or you can create the query, save it on a file and run:

```
mysql -u {username} -p {password} < /path/to/query.sql
```

Comment: not 100% sure: mysql -u {username} -p{password} {databasename} -e "FLUSH QUERY CACHE".

I updated the answer with another option.